# How can i run a command line or a cell at every 2 hours in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a small script with Python3 and i use there selenium.How can I make a command line or cell repeat every 2 hours?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc6i8.png)

I want to repeat the last cell. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried cron job on linux? I use that for re-running selenium code. You also can try GitHub action cron job. Anyway, please add a code instead of image because `imgur` is blocked in some country.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.